# Convert String to Decimal Number in Power Automate Flow

Tags: string, decimal, power-automate

My requirement is to convert string numbers to decimal numbers in Power Automate flow, Is there any way to do this?

I tried with the value() function it works in Power Apps and not in Power Automate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the `decimal()` expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#decimal